# Import SAP HANA data into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hana

I have exported some data (as binary AND .csv) from my SAP HANA system. I now want to import this into my Microsoft SQL Server using Management Studio, but apparently there is no easy way and all the tutorials on the web show the other way (from SQL to SAP HANA).
Is there a proper way to import the data?

Comment: Three off-the-top-of-my-head ideas: HANA OLE DB driver and data import export wizard in SSMS. Add your HANA as a linked server and query as normal. Or BULK INSERT your existing CSV.

Comment: Thanks, I will try out your first idea as I can't connect these two databases directly without lots of effort and import the csv-files doesn't work properly either (still looking into it)

Comment: BULK INSERT can be a pain but usually can be made to play nice. Have a look at your CSV and see if you can identify the problem, then either create a format file or pre-process the CSV with some powershell.

Answer (score 0):

The binary export can only be imported back into a SAP HANA system, so that part is pretty useless for what you want to do.
Not sure where your problem is about importing the csv export though.
The generated export directory contains the CREATE TABLE statement as well as the data in CSV format which can be imported directly to most DBMS.

Comment: Ok, the problem was with certain colums that apparantly had a different encoding format other than UTF-8. But after deleting these colums it worked.